# How To Sort Fields By Datetime

Tags: php

I have a table that contains a datetime field type, and I want to sort it on descending
My Datetime field have like this format:
12:17:23 PM  /  Thu, May 26th, 2016

And my code is

```
if($stmt=$connc->query("SELECT * FROM  static_vehicle_cat ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(edit_date_time)  DESC"))
```

Comment: You can simply use `"SELECT * FROM  static_vehicle_cat ORDER BY edit_date_time DESC"`

Comment: i am try this too but its not working 100%
i have 2 dates:  
1 - 16:04:09 PM / Fri, Apr 29th, 2016 (this is on top)  
2 - 12:28:22 PM / Thu, May 26th, 2016 (i want this on top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if column type is varchar can used this code:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(
        STR_TO_DATE(
            `edit_date_time`,
            '%h:%i:%s %p / %a,%b %D, %Y'
        ),
        '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'
    )
FROM
    `static_vehicle_cat` 
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(
        STR_TO_DATE(
            `edit_date_time`,
            '%h:%i:%s %p / %a,%b %D, %Y'
        ),
        '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'
    ) DESC
```

if column type is datetime.alter table add new column type varchar and copy edit_date_time column to new column.
after use code

Comment: Thanks Farhang, Its Working

Answer (score 0):

We can easily sort date time field using query 
Select * from storages order by last_updated desc;

Here last_updated column having date time field type